# How is 'req.session' change detected in cookie-session middleware?

Tags: node.js, cookie-session

From the [Readme.md file](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session#cookiesessionoptions), it says,

The middleware will automatically add a `Set-Cookie` header to the response if the contents of `req.session` were altered.

Where is the implementation of detecting `req.session` change? Could you point me to the code or explain me how is this change detected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an `Object.defineProperty` on https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session/blob/3dba6fb1287b19ee2f0cb3edb8a0f2afcf65bb7f/index.js#L74:

```
    Object.defineProperty(req, 'session', {
      configurable: true,
      enumerable: true,
      get: getSession,
      set: setSession <---- this one
    })
```

`setSession` is called when the propriety is assigned, and `setSession` will [set the cookie](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session/blob/3dba6fb1287b19ee2f0cb3edb8a0f2afcf65bb7f/index.js#L124)